# Rounded rectangle in RDLC Report

Tags: asp.net, report, rdlc, rounded-corners, rectangles

I have drawn rectangles and tables in my RDLC report. But I want to show rectangle's rounded corners and Black color of Table cell borders. Is there any way to do it? Or anyway I can use CSS styles in RDLC report elements?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CSS on the elements.
The ID of the ReportViewer Div is usually "1_" whatever the instance name is,
meaning if you have something like:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyReportViewer.ShowBackButton = false;
    MyReportViewer.ShowCredentialPrompts = false;
}
```

Then it -should- be given the ID="1_MyReportViewer".

This is from **my experiences with ReportViewer2008**, so this is an observation and **not exact certainty.**