# How to make an oval frame in RDLC ( Report Viewer )

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer

Is it possible to round the corners of a rectangle in rdlc Report? 
I'm trying to make an oval frame in which will be some parameter with text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything changed in that area since, but here is what I found when I was looking for similar feature: [Rounded corners on report body and header borders](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9addec44-b5ae-4cf0-8a64-b1280e45e90a/rdlrounded-corners-on-report-body-and-header-borders?forum=sqlreportingservices). I think background image is your only option and you can create it dynamically too.

Also, here is the another suggestion: [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011157/rounded-rectangle-in-rdlc-report), but I haven't tried that approach, so don't know if it works.